How to stop Animation in SwiftUI Resets Position After Window Resize and App Relaunch?
In SwiftUI, an animation is set to trigger on a view's appearance, specifically a rotation effect centered on the view. However, after resizing the app window or relaunching the app, the animation behaves unpredictably. Instead of starting from the defined center position, the animation begins from an unintended offset (on the right side of the screen) and moves back to the desired center position. This unintended animation behavior was not explicitly coded or designed and appears to be a side effect of the window resize or app lifecycle events.

macOS 12.0
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showView: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()

            TextView(color: .blue)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Show View") {
               
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    
    let color: Color
    @State private var rotationAnimation: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .bold()
            .foregroundStyle(color)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotationAnimation ? 360 : .zero), anchor: .center)
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 5.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: rotationAnimation)
            .onAppear {
                rotationAnimation = true
            }
    }
}


This answer might help: Issue with .animation in SwiftUI causing the entire view to move

Could be the insertion of the TextView is being animated, while the rotation is also being animated. What happens when you turn off the first, by setting .animation(.none) to the VStack.

@CenkBilgen: 'animation' was deprecated in macOS 12.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.
